# ios7 and later causes image icon errors

Tags: swift, image, ios7, ios8

I sucessfully submitted my app written in swift. That app was targetted for ios8 and later. Now I want to submit the same app for ios7 and later and I have a big problem. I do not know how to solve this. Error message is:

Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and apps updates submitted must support the 4 -inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with UILaunchImageSize value set to {320,568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-lvel of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/dpc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programe Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'.

Comment: side note: ios 7 market share is maybe less than 3% read this https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: I have already submitted the build to ios8 and later. I had ios 6.0 because I never updated my iPhone 5S. So I can understand, some people may still need it with ios7 and above. swift is not aimed to ios6 or prior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to add all the image formats prior to IOS 7, could be wrong...
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/